# Volatile specifier ignored in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, volatile

I'm pretty new to C++ and recently I ran across some info on what it means for a variable to be `volatile`. As far as I understood, it means a read or write to the variable can *never* be optimized out of existence.

However a weird situation arises when I declare a `volatile` variable that isn't 1, 2, 4, 8 bytes large: the compiler(gnu with C++11 enabled) seemingly ignores the `volatile` specifier

```
#define expand1 a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a, a
#define expand2 // ten expand1 here, expand3 to expand5 follows
// expand5 is the equivalent of 1e+005 a, a, ....

struct threeBytes { char x, y, z; };
struct fourBytes { char w, x, y, z; };

int main()
{
   // requires ~1.5sec
   foo<int>();

   // doesn't take time
   foo<threeBytes>();

   // requires ~1.5sec
   foo<fourBytes>();
}

template<typename T>
void foo()
{
   volatile T a;

   // With my setup, the loop does take time and isn't optimized out
   clock_t start = clock();
   for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++);
   clock_t end = clock();
   int interval = end - start;

   start = clock();
   for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) expand5;
   end = clock();

   cout << end - start - interval << endl;
}
```

Their timings are

- `foo<int>()`: ~1.5s
- `foo<threeBytes>()`: 0

I've tested it with different variables (user-defined or not) that is 1 to 8 bytes and only 1, 2, 4, 8 takes time to run. Is this a bug only existing with my setup or is `volatile` a request to the compiler and not something absolute?

PS the four byte versions always take half the time as others and is also a source of confusion

Comment: Could you post the loop code in the foo method?

Comment: What do you think the comma `,` operator actually does?

Comment: Try testing with something other than the comma operator. It doesn't do anything for any of the types in your question.

Comment: The point *is* to do nothing, because of `volatile`, it should never be ignored. 
As I mentioned, the `int` or four byte versions will take~1.5sec

Comment: can you rewrite the example with a timer included (use e.g. `<chrono>`)? It looks a bit obfuscated as it is now, why don't you just do something like `a++` inside the loops? The `struct` version will be optimized out probably, as the compiler realizes that there's no side effects, regardless of the `volatile`.

Comment: Actually there could be side effects if the struct is located at a special physical memory address: it could eg. discard bytes from a serial port IIRC.

Comment: @Ekleog yes, but the end expression is evaluated inside the loop to `a;`. This is a no-op.

Comment: @PasserBy compile with optimizations on. Your empty loop shouldn't take any time at all. The no-op loop is not a read or a write into a volatile, so the compiler is not forced to do anything. It may or may not optimize the loop.

Comment: what exactly does it mean to read? I thought any assessment of a variable means "to read" whether it does anything to it or not

Comment: @PasserBy `cout << a;` is a read of `a`. The expression `a;` by itself is a no-op, no one can use the result of the expression.

Comment: With gnu -O3, `int` still takes time while `threeBytes` doesn't

Comment: @PasserBy see my last edit, what constitutes an "access" to a `volatile` object is implementation defined. So you shouldn't expect anything. As I said, the `int` takes time because that's what the compiler wants, there is no rule saying that it should or shouldn't be optimized out. However, most of the time when you have a read or a write of a `volatile`, you won't get your loop optimized. But, since it is implementation-defined, you should consult the compiler manual and see exactly how it is implemented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The struct version will be optimized out probably, as the compiler realizes that there's no side effects (no read or write into the variable `a`), regardless of the `volatile`. You basically have a no-op, `a;`, so the compiler can do whatever it pleases it; it is not forced to unroll the loop or to optimize it out, so the `volatile` doesn't really matter here. In the case of `int`s, there seems to be no optimizations, but this is consistent with the use case of `volatile`: you should expect non-optimizations **only** when you have a possible "access to an object" (i.e. read or write) in the loop. However what constitutes "access to an object" is implementation-defined (although most of the time it follows common-sense), see **EDIT 3** at the bottom.

Toy example here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    volatile int a = 0;

    const std::size_t N = 100000000;

    // side effects, never optimized
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < N; ++i)
        ++a; // side effect (write)
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()
              <<  " ms" << std::endl;

    // no side effects, may or may not be optimized out
    start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (std::size_t i = 0 ; i < N; ++i)
        a; // no side effect, this is a no-op
    end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count()
              <<  " ms" << std::endl;
}
```

**EDIT**

The no-op is not actually optimized out for scalar types, as you can see in [this minimal example](http://ideone.com/PLSHrM). For `struct`'s though, **it is** optimized out. In the example I linked, `clang` doesn't optimize the code with no optimization, but optimizes both loops with `-O3`. `gcc` doesn't optimize out the loops either with no optimizations, but optimizes only the first loop with optimizations on.

**EDIT 2**

`clang` spits out an warning: `warning: expression result unused; assign into a variable to force a volatile load [-Wunused-volatile-lvalue]`. So my initial guess was correct, the compiler can optimize out no-ops, but it is not forced. Why does it do it for `struct`s and not scalar types is something that I don't understand, but it is the compiler's choice, and it is standard compliant. For some reason it gives this warning only when the no-op is a `struct`, and doesn't give the warning when it's a scalar type.

Also note that you don't have a "read/write", you only have a no-op, so you shouldn't expect anything from `volatile`.

**EDIT 3**

From the golden book (C++ standard)

**7.1.6.1/8 The cv-qualifiers [dcl.type.cv]**

> What constitutes an access to an object that has volatile-qualified
>   type is implementation-defined. ...

So it is up to the compiler to decide when to optimize out the loops. In most cases, it follows the common sense: when reading or writing into the object.

Comment: As I've stated before, why does `int` take time and not `threeBytes`? Not to mention I've tried with `fourBytes` which also takes time

Comment: Hmm, [expr]/p11 is interesting.

Comment: @T.C., indeed, but I guess it refers to something like `foo + 10;`, where `foo` is an object that overloads `operator+`, and the latter may have a side effect, like `cout << "hello"`. Although I have to say I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Are we looking at the same paragraph? I'm talking about the part specifying when the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to discarded-value expressions. As far as I can tell, in `a, a, a, a, a;`, each of `a` is a glvalue of volatile-qualified type, and the discarded-value expressions in that expression statement are all either an *id-expression* or a comma expression whose right operand is an *id-expression*, so [expr]/p11 requires the application of the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Comment: ...this, incidentally, means that the program is ill-formed for `fourBytes` and `threeBytes`, because their implicitly declared copy constructor cannot be used to perform the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Comment: @T.C. ohh sorry, was looking at something else. Will take a look, thanks

Answer (score 4):

This question is a lot more interesting than it first appears (for some definition of "interesting"). It looks like you've found a compiler bug (or intentional nonconformance), but it isn't quite the one you are expecting.

According to the standard, one of your `foo` calls has undefined behavior, and the other two are ill-formed. I'll first explain what should happen; the relevant standard quotes can be found after the break. For our purposes, we can just analyze the simple expression statement `a, a, a;` given `volatile T a;`.

`a, a, a` in this expression statement is a discarded-value expression ([stmt.expr]/p1). The type of the expression `a, a, a` is the type of the right operand, which is the *id-expression* `a`, or `volatile T`; since `a` is an lvalue, so is the expression `a, a, a` ([expr.comma]/p1). Thus, this expression is an lvalue of a volatile-qualified type, and it is a "comma expression where the right operand is one of these expressions" - in particular, an *id-expression* - and therefore [expr]/p11 requires the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion be applied to the expression `a, a, a`. Similarly, inside `a, a, a`, the left expression `a, a` is also a discarded-value expression, and inside this expression the left expression `a` is also a discarded-value expression; similar logic shows that [expr]/p11 requires the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion be applied to both the result of the expression `a, a` and the result of the expression `a` (the leftmost one).

If `T` is a class type (either `threeBytes` or `fourBytes`), applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion entails creating a temporary by copy-initialization from the volatile lvalue `a` ([conv.lval]/p2). However, the implicitly declared copy constructor always takes its argument by a non-volatile reference ([class.copy]/p8); such a reference cannot bind to a volatile object. Therefore, the program is ill-formed.

If `T` is `int`, then applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion yields the value contained in `a`. However, in your code, `a` is never initialized; this evaluation therefore produces an indeterminate value, and per [dcl.init]/p12, results in undefined behavior.

---

Standard quotes follows. All are from C++14:

[expr]/p11:

> In some contexts, an expression only appears for its side effects.
>   Such an expression is called a *discarded-value expression*. The
>   expression is evaluated and its value is discarded. The
>   array-to-pointer (4.2) and function-to- pointer (4.3) standard
>   conversions are not applied. The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is
>   applied if and only if the expression is a glvalue of
>   volatile-qualified type and it is one of the following:
>
> - ( *expression* ), where *expression* is one of these expressions,
> - *id-expression* (5.1.1),
> - [several inapplicable bullets omitted], or
> - comma expression (5.18) where the right operand is one of these expressions.
>
> [ *Note*: Using an overloaded operator causes a function call; the
>   above covers only operators with built-in meaning. If the lvalue is of
>   class type, it must have a volatile copy constructor to initialize the
>   temporary that is the result of the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion. —*end
>   note* ]

[expr.comma]/p1:

> A pair of expressions separated by a comma is evaluated left-to-right;
>   the left expression is a discarded-value expression (Clause 5) [...] The type 
>   and value of the result are the type and value of the right operand;
>   the result is of the same value category as its right operand [...].

[stmt.expr]/p1:

> Expression statements have the form
>
> ```
> expression-statement:
>     expression_opt;
> ```
>
> The expression is a discarded-value expression (Clause 5).

[conv.lval]/p1-2:

> 1 A glvalue (3.10) of a non-function, non-array type `T` can be
>   converted to a prvalue. If `T` is an incomplete type, a program that
>   necessitates this conversion is ill-formed. If `T` is a non-class
>   type, the type of the prvalue is the cv-unqualified version of `T`.
>   Otherwise, the type of the prvalue is T.
>
> 2 [some special rules not relevant here] In all other cases, the
>   result of the conversion is determined according to the following
>   rules:
>
> - [inapplicable bullet omitted]
> - Otherwise, if `T` has a class type, the conversion copy-initializes a temporary of type `T` from the glvalue and the result of the
>     conversion is a prvalue for the temporary.
> - [inapplicable bullet omitted]
> - Otherwise, the value contained in the object indicated by the glvalue is the prvalue result.

[dcl.init]/p12:

> If no initializer is specified for an object, the object is
>   default-initialized. When storage for an object with automatic or
>   dynamic storage duration is obtained, the object has an indeterminate
>   value, and if no initialization is performed for the object, that
>   object retains an indeterminate value until that value is replaced
>   (5.17). [...] If an indeterminate value is produced by an evaluation,
>   the behavior is undefined except in the following cases: [certain
>   inapplicable exceptions related to unsigned narrow character types]

[class.copy]/p8:

> The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class `X` will have the
>   form
>
> ```
> X::X(const X&)
> ```
>
> if each potentially constructed subobject of a class type `M` (or
>   array thereof) has a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type
>   `const M&` or `const volatile M&`. Otherwise, the implicitly-declared
>   copy constructor will have the form
>
> ```
> X::X(X&)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

`volatile` doesn't do what you think it does.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2016.html

If you're relying on `volatile` outside of the three very specific uses Boehm mentions on the page I linked, you're going to get unexpected results.

Comment: Pretty sure the OP is not using `volatile` for atomicity so I'm not sure what you're answering.

Comment: Well, OP seems to be expecting `volatile` to force the compiler to create no-op reads that do nothing.  See @vsoftco's Edit #3 above.