# Discarded value expressions of volatile class type behave differently than those of volatile built-in types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, volatile

Consider this following piece of code:

```
struct S{
  int i;
  S(int);
  S(const volatile S&);
  };

struct S_bad{
  int i;
  };

volatile S     as{0};
volatile S_bad as_bad{0};
volatile int   ai{0};

void test(){
   ai;     //(1)=> a load is always performed
   as;     //(2)=> Should call the volatile copy constructor
   as_bad; //(3)=> Should be ill-formed
   }
```

The expression `ai;`, `as;` and `as_bad` are discarded value expressions and according to the C++ draft standard [N4659/[expr].12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#12) I expected that an [lvalue-to-rvalue](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.lval) would have applied in these three cases. For case (2) this should cause a call to the volatile copy constructor (`S(const volatile S&)`) [[expr]/12](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4618/expr#12)

> [...]If the expression is a prvalue after this optional conversion, the temporary materialization conversion ([conv.rval]) is applied. [ Note: If the expression is an lvalue of class type, it must have a volatile copy constructor to initialize the temporary that is the result object of the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.  — end note ]

So the case (3) should be ill-formed.

Nevertheless, the behavior of compilers seems chaotic:

1. GCC:

   - `ai;` => loads the value of `ai`;
   - `as;` => no code generated, no warning;
   - `as_bad;` => loads `as_bad.i`.
2. Clang does not produce a load for case (2) and generates the warning: *expression result unused; assign into a variable to force a volatile load [-Wunused-volatile-lvalue]*

   - `ai;` => loads the value of `ai`;
   - `as;` => no code generated; warning *expression result unused; assign into a variable to force a volatile load [-Wunused-volatile-lvalue]*
   - `as_bad;` => same as `as;`.
3. MSVC performs the load in both cases.

   - `ai;` => loads the value of `ai`;
   - `as;` => loads `as.i` (without calling to the volatile copy constructor)
   - `as_bad;` => loads `as_bad.i`.

Summary of what I expected according to the standard:

- `ai;` => loads the value of `ai`;
- `as;` => call `S(const volatile S&)` with `as` as argument;
- `as_bad;` => generate a compilation error

Is my interpretation of the standard right? Which compiler is right if any?

Comment: That's kind of hard to answer, I think. The rules of the abstract machine definitely demand an access here. And a conforming program must have that access be present. But, does "access" mean that a "load must happen"? I don't know. The standard doesn't dictate a specific implementation for "access".

Comment: @StoryTeller Are not accesses to volatiles observable behaviour?

Comment: Yes. But we must be careful when assuming the absract "access" always translates 1-to-1 with "machine load instruction".

Comment: @StoryTeller, May be this [linked code](https://godbolt.org/g/pPzWeN) does not offer the compiler any possible interpretation. I thought the compiler should have called the copy constructor of `s`, why it does not?

Comment: I can't say for sure. My gut instinct tells me it has something to do with `as` and `ai` being objects declared and created by the compiler itself. So it allows itself to be more lax, as opposed to any access by some general glvalue, such as `constexpr volatile int* p = static_cast<volatile int*>(0xf00ba7);`

Comment: I say they're all wrong, because `S` doesn't have a copy constructor that can copy from `volatile`s, so the temporary materialization conversion cannot be performed. None of them uses the copy constructor, even if it's user-provided.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Volatile specifier ignored in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29868792/volatile-specifier-ignored-in-c)

Comment: The question isn't as well written, but there are pretty complete answers there

Comment: @PasserBy, Actualy may interpretation was wrong, actualy it is clearly stated in the standard that the expression `as;` is ill-formed. I had the sitation. Unfortunately this change substantialy the question. Should not I write a new one?

Comment: @Oliv You can self-answer if you found the answer after asking, and post another question

Comment: It's normally considered OK to substantially edit a question if no answer has been posted

Comment: @M.M. OK I did it, but now the question is old and has no more visibility => I can add a bounty.

Comment: Editing bumps the question;  I'll remove my comments that pertain to the old code now. Although I retain the point that *compile error* is not something specified by the Standard; `as_bad` must *generate a diagnostic*, and a warning is a diagnostic.

Comment: @M.M. I ll wash my comments too. I do not see the question as bumped in any list, where can you see it?

Comment: Sorry, my understanding of the site was that it would bump the question, or keep showing it to people who haven't seen it yet; I don't know any more on that front. There have been many times in the past I've had an old question appear at the top of my front page when it had just been edited , so I figured that was what was happening.

Comment: @M.M. Thanks so I add a bounty!

Comment: @PasserBy I think I have substantialy changed the question, I think the "this question may already have an answer" could be removed.

Comment: [Correct behaviour of trivial statements involving expressions with volatile variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20242868/1708801) may be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. C++03 said that the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion doesn't happen for the result of an expression statement, and doesn't explicitly say that a copy occurs when the conversion happens anyway.
2. C++11 says, as you stated, that the conversion does happen for volatile objects, and that the conversion involves copying to make a temporary.
3. C++14 merely cleans up the wording (to avoid silly things like `b ? (x,y) : z` not counting if `y` does) and adds the note about the volatile copy constructor.
4. C++17 applies the temporary materialization conversion to preserve the previous meaning.

So my conclusion is that (as of C++11) you are correct and all the compilers are wrong.  In particular, the `S::i` load shouldn't happen unless your copy constructor reads it.  The implementation-defined nature of "access" is irrelevant to the question of what is well-formed, of course; it only affects whether the load instruction for `ai` is actually generated.  There is the issue of `S_bad` being an aggregate, but that is irrelevant since it's not being list-initialized.

Comment: What is the "issue of S_bad being aggregate"?

Comment: @Oliv: Objects of an aggregate type can be initialized without invoking any constructor.

Comment: but they have an implicit copy constructor, which will be called for temporary materialization.

Comment: @Oliv: Right—because this isn’t list-initialization, like I said.

Comment: Could I put a link from [GCC bug 84699](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84699) to your answer? Or maybe you could add it yourself, it could be more valueable. It is still marked as unconfirmed, I believe it could make this bug report be confirmed (essentialy because I have no idea of the process of bug confirmation).